# Cannot sending multiple form fields formdata dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, input, form-data, dropzone.js

I'm having a problem sending the images have a text area field for the client to send a description of the photo, and when he sent to the database sends as if all had the same description that was being inserted only one description,

I'm using the library DROPZONE.JS http://dropzonejs.com/

Follow my code .. Help me please.

```
Dropzone.options.upload = {
    thumbnailWidth: 246,
    thumbnailHeight: 173,
    enqueueForUpload:false,
    paramName: "userfile",
    sending: function(file, xhr, formData) {    
        formData.append("titulo", $("#titulo").val());
        formData.append("evento", <?php echo $this->uri->segment(4); ?>);
        formData.append("capa", $("#cap").val());
    }
};

function upload() {
    var dz = Dropzone.forElement("#upload");
    for (var i = 0; i < dz.files.length; i++) {
        dz.filesQueue.push(dz.files[i]);
    }
    dz.processQueue(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated there can only be one DOM element having an id in the whole document or you will have issues.  This can be solved on the fly by adding the file name to the id of your text box field.

Add code for your text box in the previewTemplate

```
previewTemplate: "<div class=\"dz-preview dz-file-preview\"> ...
<input type=\"text\" class=\"titulo\" data-dz-titulo >
...
data-dz-errormessage></span></div>\n</div>"
```

When the previewTemplate is rendered by the addedfile function create an id called titulo + file.name to give your element a unique id. This can be done by adding a line of code in the addedfile function.

```
addedfile: function(file) {
    file.previewElement = Dropzone.createElement(this.options.previewTemplate);
    ...
    file.previewElement.querySelector("[data-dz-titulo]").id = "titulo" + file.name;
    ...
    file.previewElement.querySelector("[data-dz-size]").innerHTML = this.filesize(file.size);
},
```

Now you will also have to use the file name to get the matching titulo in the sending function.

```
sending: function(file, xhr, formData) {
    var filetitulo = document.getElementById('titulo' +file.name).value;
    formData.append("titulo", filetitulo);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `$("#titulo")` you refer to the input / textarea having the id of titulo.

For example `<input type="text" id="titulo">`.

There can only be one DOM element having an id in the whole document.

Change your element to `<input type="text" class="titulo">` then you use something like `$(".titulo")[0]`, `$(".titulo")[1]` to select the fields.